# display date system in h:inputText

Tags: date, jsf

How to display the time and date of the system in real time on a inputText or tag calendar in jsf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF does not have a component that allows you to do that quickly, but there implemetaciones Primefaces jsf as having ready components.

```
<p:clock pattern="HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy" mode="server" />
```

[Clock](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/clock.xhtml)